# How to rectify this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textbox

What is the problem with below code, why it doesn't work for me..!!! I am unable to fetch selected data and display it on text box.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {                                       
    $("#name").on("change", function() {
    $("#Fname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    })
 });  

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<select id="Fname" name ="name">
<option value="">Choose Your Value</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="US">US</option>
<option value="UAE">UAE</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>    

</select>

<input type="text" id="Fname" value ="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

the select and the input, have the sane id "Fname".

Comment: dude.. i changed it as per you said. but still it doesn't work

Comment: Try $(this).val() instead $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")

Answer (score 1):

You have given the ID for input box and select box same.

Both have id = "Fname"

Moreover when you find using $("#") it should be an id of the DOM in your case its a name.

However i have corrected your code here.

---

```
<html>
   </head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#Fname").on("change", function() { 
        $("input").val($(this).val());   
      }) });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <select id="Fname" name ="name">
            <option value="">Choose Your Value</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
            <option value="US">US</option>
            <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
            <option value="China">China</option>
            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
         </select>
         <input type="text" id="Fname" value ="" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could anyone tell me... how to insert add button to choose more items textbox from same drpDwn list . like if user want to add more items it should displayed in textbox one by one

Answer (score 1):

Change id of  Either `select` or `input` and apply it in JQUery will solve your issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                       
    $("#Fname").on("change", function() {

    $("#SFname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    })
 });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqjcam9d/)

**Edit:**

You can add multiple value to text box like:

```
$("#SFname").val($("#SFname").val() + " " + $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    })
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/pqjcam9d/1/)

Comment: from the above link which u 've given , it displays the value in same text box only. i need multiple textboxes for each and every select...

Comment: @Begginer_Baby means different textbox added dynamically?

Comment: yeah..  if choose apple from list it should displayed in textbx with apple and then i have add button to add more fruits one by one followed by apple

Comment: Ok. I think it is different question and it has to do little bit more. So, i think you have to ask it as a different question.

Comment: yes actually... ahhha...am doing battle with AngularJS :(

Comment: Good. And accept any of one as a answer from this question by click on right symbol. all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This Code Inter Net is mandatory or copy jquery.min.js. the problem is u mentioned same name for select tag id and input text id as same.

```
  <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#name").on("change", function() { $("#Fname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")); }) });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<select id="name" name ="name">
<option value="">Choose Your Value</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="US">US</option>
<option value="UAE">UAE</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>    

</select>

<input type="text" id="Fname" value ="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sravan, i did changes in select and input tag, but still same problem.

Comment: can u able to access "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" url. its must and should or download and add this js

Comment: Sravan. could you please tell me...!!! now i want to introduce Add button which enables user to add more items from same dropDownList, that should be displayed one by one in text box. could anyone help me to complete this please. am totally new to programming..!!! i seek your help after tried so many times..

Comment: instad of <select id="name" name ="name"> use <select id="name" name ="name" multiple>